# MongoDB - Aplicar filtro sobre resultado de un $group y $project

Tags: java, mongodb

tengo un problema para obtener un resultado con una consulta en el shell de MongoDB. Aparentemente, la estructura de la información almacenada no es tan compleja, y tampoco debería serlo la consulta, pero no lo he logrado. 
Además, tengo que tener cuidado con el tiempo de procesamiento, ya que tengo miles de miles de registros, y lanzarme a una consulta muy compleja me llevaría mucho tiempo de respuesta. 
Los documentos almacenados tienen esta estructura:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0ed238d921d920a0997b9a"),
    "id" : "ABC",
    "className" : "Processing",
    "error" : false,
    "registerDate" : ISODate("2018-05-30T11:32:31.000-05:00")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0ed239d921d920a0997b9b"),
    "id" : "PQR",
    "className" : "Processing",
    "error" : false,
    "registerDate" : ISODate("2018-05-30T11:32:40.000-05:00")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0ed239d921d920a0997b9c"),
    "id" : "XYZ",
    "className" : "Processing",
    "error" : true,
    "registerDate" : ISODate("2018-05-30T11:32:40.000-05:00")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b11c233f3bad457380ef33a"),
    "id" : "ABC",
    "senderClass" : "Sender",
    "senderError" : false,
    "registerDate" : ISODate("2018-06-01T17:01:22.000-05:00")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b11c233f3bad457380ef33b"),
    "id" : "PQR",
    "senderClass" : "Sender",
    "senderError" : true,
    "registerDate" : ISODate("2018-06-01T17:01:22.000-05:00")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b14c2jh3kk43k4j80ef15js"),
    "id" : "PQR",
    "senderClass" : "Sender",
    "senderError" : false,
    "registerDate" : ISODate("2018-06-01T17:03:72.000-07:00")
}
```

En la colección, se almacenan dos tipos de documentos: de procesamiento y de envío.

- Cada evento procesado, tiene un ID, pero en caso falle una vez, puede
  reintentarse hasta 3 veces con el mismo ID. Por lo tanto, pueden
  llega a haber 3 registros con el mismo ID
- Una vez procesado será enviado, y si falla el envío puede
  reintentarse hasta 3 veces y también usa el mismo ID. Como en el
  ejemplo: el evento PQR es procesado una vez sin error (error=false)
  y enviado 2 veces (la primera con senderError=true y la segunda
  con senderError=false).
- Si el evento llega al límite de reintentos en procesamiento sin
  éxito, no será enviado (como en el caso del evento XYZ).

En la consulta que necesito hacer, deseo obtener un resultado de este tipo:

```
{
    "_id" : "ABC",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-06-01T17:03:31.000-05:00"),
    "failedSend" : false     //No falló envío
}
{
    "_id" : "PQR",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-06-01T17:03:36.000-05:00"),
    "failedSend" : false     //No falló envío
}
{
    "_id" : "XYZ",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-06-01T17:32:40.000-05:00"),
    "failedSend" : true      //Si falló envío
}
```

Donde se me indique **si finalmente el evento se envió o no**. Hay dos formas de saber que el documento no se envió:

- Falló reiteradas veces en el procesamiento y no llegó a enviarse.
  (Tendrá el campo error=true)
- No falló en el procesamiento, pero si reiteradas veces en el envío. Y
  en estas condiciones el evento SI se envía:
- Se procesó bien (ya sea al primer o n reintentos) y luego se envío
  bien (en el primer o n reintentos). (Como en el caso del evento con
  id PQR, que al primer intento de envío no funciona pero al segundo sí
  ).

Yo he construido la siguiente consulta:

```
db.trace.aggregate([
 {
      $match :
      {
          $and : 
              [
                   {registerDate : { $gt: new Date( '05/15/2018' ) } },
                   //Aquí no se como construir el filtro para que me liste los eventos que fallaron o los que no
              ]
      }
 },
 {
      $group : { 
          _id : "$id", 
          date: {$last : "$registerDate"},
          sendStates : { $push : "$senderError" }
      } 
 },
 {
     $skip : 0
 },
 {
     $limit : 50
 },
 {
     $project:
     {
        date: 1,
        failedSend : 
            {
                $cond: {
               if: { $allElementsTrue: [ "$sendStates" ] },
               then: true,
               else: false
               }
            }
     }
 }
 ]
)
```

Como verán, la consulta tiene dos parámetros para hacer el filtro:

- La fecha a partir de la cual se desean obtener los datos
- Si se envío o no el correo.

La consulta me parece que funciona sin el segundo filtro (me devuelve cuales fueron enviados y cuales no a partir de la fecha indicada), pero quiero que me devuelva solo los que si fueron enviados o los que no, dependiendo el parámetro que le pase.
Y eso ya me lleva dos días y no logro :(

**Nota adicional:** Creo que la consulta mejoraría si almaceno los documentos anidados, sin embargo **no puedo cambiar la estructua de almacenamiento de los documentos**. A parte que ya son muchísimos, que hacer la consulta que he construido lleva casi un minuto :(
Luego tendré que pasar toda la consulta a Java, pero primero quiero asegurarme que funciona en el shell de Mongo.

Porfa ayuda :( gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución utilizando otro bloque match luego del bloque project. No sabía que podía realizar 2 veces un match dentro de una mismo aggregate, pero eso me ayudó a mostrar los resultados haciendo un filtro sobre los datos que ya tenía.
Aquí dejo el script final:

```
db.trace.aggregate([
 {
      $match : {registerDate : { $gt: new Date( '05/15/2018' ) } }
 },
 {
      $group : { 
          _id : "$id", 
          date: {$last : "$registerDate"},
          sendStates : { $push : "$senderError" }
      } 
 },
 {
     $skip : 0
 },
 {
     $limit : 50
 },
 {
     $project:
     {
        date: 1,
        failedSend : 
            {
                $cond: {
               if: { $allElementsTrue: [ "$sendStates" ] },
               then: true,
               else: false
               }
            }
     }
 },
 {
     $match :
      {
          failedSend : true
      }
 }
 ]
)
```